# Prepopulating Form Data Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form where users get edit their personal information/settings and I'm trying to get it to pre-populate if they have entered that information in the past.  I looked here:

[Django prepopulate form with the fields from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095229/django-prepopulate-form-with-the-fields-from-the-database)

for help, but still can't get the form to prepopulate.  Thanks in advance.

```
#model

    class UserProfile(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
        address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
        address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
        address_line_3 = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
        postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
        paypal_email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, blank=True)
        photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True)


        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user.username

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                existing = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.user)
                self.id = existing.id #force update instead of insert
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                pass 
            models.Model.save(self, *args, **kwargs)


    #form
    class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            exclude = ('user', 'activation_key',)

    # view
    def update_settings(request):
        if request.method== 'POST':
            try:
                u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=u)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid:
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = request.user
                profile.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('registration/activation_complete.html')
        else:
            try:
                u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=u)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            return render_to_response('registration/update_settings.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Why do you use `request.POST` when `request.method != 'POST'`?

Comment: sorry not sure i follow Tadeck when the user submits the form to update their data, isn't that a 'POST' ?

Comment: Do you have a `@login_required` decorator? Also, `is_valid` should be `is_valid()`

Comment: yes i have @login_required decorator thanks for catching the missing parenthesis

Comment: @Jonathan: I am referring to the part of the script that begins after the only line you have with "`else:`" content in it. Everything that happens when the script falls into that `else` case happens, because the `request.method == 'POST'` condition was not met (in other words, in that `else` case, it is true that `request.method != 'POST'`). I do not know if I can explain it to you clearer.

Comment: @tadeck that was the error! thanks!

Comment: Maybe, it prepopultaes with the instance but then overwritting with no data from the POST-variable. Also u will have a problem if the form isn't valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update your view code like this:

```
def update_settings(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
        try:
            u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=u)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():  #is_valid is function not property
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('registration/activation_complete.html')
    else:
        try:
            u = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            form = UserProfileForm(instance=u) #No request.POST
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            form = UserProfileForm(request.FILES)
   # move it outside of else
   return render_to_response('registration/update_settings.html', locals(),
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```